# Writing acceptance test to terraform module and transfer it to resource acceptance test

Tags: go, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I was wondering if I can take a module let's say `ec2_instances` module and write an acceptance test to it within Golang.

I also attached a function that tests a resource of customer provider I wrote although I have no clue how to make the connection between the two.

```
locals {
  nodes = toset(["a", "b", "c"])
}

module "ec2_instances" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version = "~> 3.0"

  for_each = local.nodes

  name = "${each.key}.ravendb"

  ami                    = "ami-09e67e426f25ce0d7" 
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  key_name               = "omer-tf"
  monitoring             = false
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-03525214aee516d50"]
  subnet_id              = "subnet-0ee70783a7dd19aa5"
  associate_public_ip_address   = true
  # ebs {
  #     # avoid data loss is changing the configuration and TF decides to terminate the instance
  #     # real world scenario should have dedicated EBS volumes resources managed separately from instances
  #   delete_on_termination = false
  # }
} 


func TestAccResourceRavenDbServer(t *testing.T) {
    var (
        resourceName = "resource_ravendb_server.test"
    )

    resource.ParallelTest(t, resource.TestCase{
        PreCheck: func() {
            testAccPreCheck(t)
            checkAwsEnv(t)
        },
        ProviderFactories: testAccProviderFactories,
        CheckDestroy:      testAccRavenDbServerDestroy,
        Steps: []resource.TestStep{
            {
                Config: testAccRavenDbServerConfig(),
                Check: resource.ComposeTestCheckFunc(
                    resource.TestCheckResourceAttr(resourceName, "healthcheck_database", "firewire"),
                ),
            },
        },
    })
}
```

Comment: [This](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/testing-experiment.html)?

Comment: Use https://terratest.gruntwork.io/. They got it right.

Comment: @marco.m can you provide example for module because I have not seen one over there

Comment: Terratest is about testing Terraform modules :-) Take the time to go through the documentation and the examples, it is all open source.